# OSX Launchd /Library/LaunchDaemons

Tags: macos, launchd

I have created a plist file (see below) and stuck it into /Library/LaunchDaemons/ .  (It starts a virtualbox via a script that runs VBoxHeadless .)  I can start the plist as user "nobody"

```
sudo -u nobody launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.somename.plist
```

and it runs fine (launchctl list | grep -i org.somename).  but it is not picked up by itself upon boot.

```
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>             <string>org.somename</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>          <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>         <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>         <false/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/someuser/somename.sh</string>
            <string>restart</string>
        </array>
</dict>
```

and this plist is chown 600 and chmod root.  moreover somename.sh says

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless -s somevm
```

what could I be missing?

is there a complete step-by-step checklist somewhere of what it takes to get a program to run at boot time??  I remember the "good old times" where I would stick a command into /etc/rc.local , and it would just work....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add the following lines before your `</dict>` tag:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/org.somename.plist.err</string>

<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/org.somename.plist.out</string>
```

Then you should be able to check this files and hopefully you get more info of what happened.

Comment: this was very helpful.  it tells me that the VBoxHeadless Kernel driver is not installed (err -1908 in suplibOsInit).  I need a mechanism to sequence LaunchDaemons, perhaps by sleeping, but better by dependency marking.

Comment: I thought it was very useful and I +1 it, but a complete solution would have to provide a checklist, preferably with ways of checking after each step that "we are on track"